# Android Storage(MediaStore)

Tags: android, kotlin, file, mediastore, android-storage

## i am trying to save the audio files from the cache to a music directory having a folder Voice Changer

the below code is working fine in android 10 and above
but below that its not working
I'm currently facing a challenge while working with the MediaStore API in Android 8. This API is used for managing media files like images and videos in Android applications. Specifically, I'm having trouble adding files using this API. In Android development, being able to effectively handle media files is crucial, but I've encountered obstacles in this process.
I've tried to dig into the problem, but the solution has eluded me so far. I'm exploring different avenues and troubleshooting methods to pinpoint the problem and find a resolution. I believe that with a bit more effort and perhaps some external insights, I can overcome this hurdle and continue with my Android development projects effectively

```
suspend fun String.saveAudioToGallery(
    context: Context, mimeType: String = "audio/x-wav", done: (String?) -> Unit, error: () -> Unit
) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    var savedPath: String? = null
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "Vc_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.wav")
        put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, mimeType)
        put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000)
    }
    val collection = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        contentValues.put(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH,
            "${Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC}/VoiceChanger"
        )
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
    } else {
        val directory =
            File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).absolutePath,"VoiceChanger")
        if (!directory.exists()){
            directory.mkdirs()
        }
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, directory.absolutePath)
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString())
    }
    val contentResolver = context.contentResolver

    try {
        // Insert the audio file into the MediaStore and get the URI
        val audioUri = contentResolver.insert(collection, contentValues)
        Log.d("inputStram", "saveAudioToGalleryUri:$audioUri ")


        audioUri?.let { uri ->
            // Open an output stream using the ContentResolver
            contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri)?.use { os ->
                // Open input stream from the file path
                val file = File(this@saveAudioToGallery)
                val inputStream = FileInputStream(file)
                // Write audio data to the output stream
                inputStream.copyTo(os)
                Log.d("inputStram", "saveAudioToGallery:$savedPath ")
                savedPath = file.absolutePath // Save the file path for later use
                Log.d("inputStram", "saveAudioToGallery:$savedPath ")
                os.close()
                inputStream.close()
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // Handle exceptions
        Log.e("TAG", "saveAudioToGallery: ${e.message}")
    }

    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        if (savedPath != null) {
            Log.d("TAGGing", "saveAudioToGallery:$savedPath ")
            done.invoke(savedPath)
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context.applicationContext, "Failed to save audio to gallery", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            error.invoke()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does not work? You let us guess now.

Comment: if (!directory.exists()){
            if(!directory.mkdirs()) return;
        } . Display a Toast too to inform the user.

Comment: `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, directory.absolutePath)` Think that the .DATA column expects full path of new file. Not only full path of directory.

Comment: @blackapps in android below 10 dir is made and then the files are not stored in side that  folder named Voice changer
the audioUri is returned always null
issue comes in resolver.insert(collection,contentValues)

Comment: You did not react on what i said about the .DATA column.

Comment: i had previously used that as well but i didnot get the required result
@blackapps

Comment: Quite possible as you have an exception. Why didnt you tell us about it?

Comment: i tried that also but that wasnot working

Comment: can u refer me some article other than docs where i could get the precise and easy handling memory with mediaStore?

Answer (score 0):

For below 10 you use an impossible collection which causes for an exception that you did not tell us.

Further you should give the .DATA columf full path of the file. Not only full path of the directory.